# How to provide a service to query sql sever with caching?

Tags: javascript, jquery, sql-server

I need to provide a service to access sql server tables and retrieve the results in json format.

Afterwards the results are parsed in a jquery UI.
The required data will not be updated frequently, but should be presented to the user on each access to the UI.
I fear that querying sql server on each UI request will decrease the performance.

what solution could you advice?
Maybe some caching mechanism?
I was thinking of writing the DB-access in java.

Comment: You can store that data in any data structure you want on your server, You don't have to hit your DB then

Comment: But how would I know when the data IS updated in the DB?

Comment: Easy. Each time you update the data, update the data structure.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

.Net has support for this out-of-the-box using [`SqlCacheDependency`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.caching.sqlcachedependency.aspx). This works by caching any query result and then relies on the [SQL Server Query Notification](http://rusanu.com/2006/06/17/the-mysterious-notification/) mechanism to actively invalidate the cache whenever data changes. Unfortunately Query Notifications have no support in Java.